# batch compare a string

Tags: batch-file, compare

I want to compare an input string to another string, and if it doesn´t match I want it to write it to a document. I came up with this:

```
echo Correct this sentence:
echo ----------------------
echo.
echo 'me has been shoppping with my freinds'

set sentence1=
set /p sentence1=Answer:
echo Your answer was: "%sentence1%"
pause
```

Does someone out there have a hint?

Comment: `IF "%string1%" equ "%string2%" echo strings are equal`

Comment: Is there also something like non-equ?

Comment: Yep - `IF NOT "%string1%" equ "%string2%" echo strings are NOT equal` or `IF "%string1%" neq "%string2%" echo strings are equal`

Comment: @npocmaka shouldn't the second one be **not** equal as well?

Comment: @DennisvanGils - ooh yes. In the echoed message.

Comment: And how does that work with multiple strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either something simple as `%sentence1%==%sentence2%` or use `find` if you save sentences to files.

```
if not %sentence1%==%sentence2% (
    echo %sentence1% > file.txt
    ::to append use ">>"
)
```

or

```
echo 'me has been shoppping with my freinds' > file.txt
find "%sentence1%" in "file.txt"
if %errorlevel%==1 (
    echo Sentence is not the same
)
```

And `find` also works the way only a word is enough and if a word is present in file, it'll behave like it found the sentence. For example `"me"` would mark the sentence as the same, but `"me with"` wouldn't. The secnd option may be useful if you'd want to target a specific word/word combination for a mistake e.g. `"me has"`.